# Sync framework 4.0 with store app working sample or code implementation

Tags: synchronization, windows-store-apps, microsoft-sync-framework

I need to use sync framework 4.0 just as POC . I have VS2013 Express for windows store and table as well as VS2013 Web Express and SQL Server 2012 which i believe is enough to implement this framework . 
The solution which i found is required Professional or Ultimate version of VS ([link Which i tried](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mim/archive/2013/06/18/sync-framework-with-sqlite-for-windows-store-apps-winrt-and-windows-phone-8.aspx)). one more thing is i did not find any sample which content step by step to its implementation . codes i am getting in bits and pieces or its obsolete like using vs2010 and window 7 . i have spent a good time in search of Sync Framework implementation in windows phone , store app but no luck . i hope there should be very elegant way to implement this in order to just create a sample app. if anybody has used this or having any suggestion please let me know . Code snippets , sample code and references will be highly appreciable .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there's no Sync Framework 4.0, you must be referring to Sync Framework Toolkit. have a look at this instead: https://github.com/Mimetis/SyncWinRT